# How to display only the 3 wanted rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

MY query:

```
Select
    email_address,
    count(customer_id) AS order_count,
    sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS order_total, 
    avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS avg_order_total
from customers join orders
using(customer_id)
join order_items
using(order_id)
group by
    customer_id,
    email_address
order by
    avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) desc
```

[image: My output]

[image: Expected output]

I'm not sure how to only display the 3 wanted rows and make the avg_order_total
rounded to 2 decimal places. Can't use limits

Comment: On what basis are these 3 wanted?

Comment: check expected output

Comment: `check expected output` ... your logic is not clear, hence we are asking.

Comment: I did they appear to be all male.

Comment: you are talking like a manager, **check expected output**

Comment: What are your criteria for the rows you want? Is it where order_count > 1 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

this is your right query!

```
select
    email_address,
    count(customer_id) AS order_count,
    sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS order_total, 
    avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS avg_order_total
from customers join orders
using(customer_id)
join order_items
using(order_id)
group by
    customer_id,
    email_address
order by
    sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) desc
limit 3
```

if you can't use limit then you can only read first three results at application level.

Answer (score -1):

Add `limit 3` to your sql query.

Comment: forgot to mention, cant use limits

Comment: Even if i did, its not limited to the output I wanted

Comment: @123_abcD may I ask why?